# Emacs converts character to raw-byte when inserting

Tags: character-encoding

In this example, there is a character bearing number `182` with a string equivalent of `¶`.  When evaluating the string at issue, the character is displayed correctly in the echo area.  When trying to insert the string into a buffer or generate a `message`, the character is converted into `\266` described by Emacs as a *raw-byte*.  How can this string be inserted into the buffer as `¶` rather than `\266`?

**EXAMPLE**:

`(message (let ((str "foo")) (aset str 2 ?\¶) str))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an experiment you can try:

```el
(let ((str "foo")) (aset str 2 ?¶) str)
"fo\266"

(let ((str (string-to-multibyte "foo"))) (aset str 2 ?¶) str)
"fo¶"
```

If I do

```el
(let ((str1 "foo") (str2 (string-to-multibyte "foo"))) (string-equal str1 str2))
t
(let ((str1 "foo") (str2 (string-to-multibyte "foo"))) (aset str1 2 ?¶) (aset str2 2 ?¶) (string-equal str1 str2))
nil
```

So there *must* be a difference but I don't know how to tell (I've also tried with `equal` instead of `string-equal` with no change). If it makes a difference, the language environment was `UTF-8`.

EDIT: Here's another experiment that actually shows the difference in a more fundamental way:

```el
(setq str "foo")
"foo"
(multibyte-string-p str)
nil
(string-bytes str)
3
(aset str 2 ?¶)
182
(string-bytes str)
3

(setq str (string-to-multibyte "foo"))
"foo"
(multibyte-string-p str)
t
(string-bytes str)
3
(aset str 2 ?¶)
182
(string-bytes str)
4
```

I think now it *is* an answer :-)